# android webview doesnt load facebook correctly

Tags: android, browser, webview, native

My webview android browser doesnt load facebook page correctly. On native browser it looks like this:

[image]

but on my `WebView` like this:

[image]

I can`t figure out what is the reason, here is my code:

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NORMAL);
        web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

web.setNetworkAvailable(true);

        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView web, int progress) {

                if (progress < 100
                        && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE
                        && isConnected) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    textProgress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }

                if (progress < 100
                        && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.VISIBLE
                        && textProgress.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.VISIBLE) {

                    textProgress.setText(String.format(getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.browser_loading), progress));
                }

                if (progress >= 100) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    textProgress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }

            }

        });

        if (isConnected) {

            web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap map) {

                    return;

                }

                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    web.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;

                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                }

            });

            web.loadUrl(url);
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the mobile website in your webview link i.e https://m.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FBDialog](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/v1.0/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/FbDialog.java) which is used by Facebook SDK to show the web dialog , you can copy required code from that. It also shows `ProgressDialog` while loading page.